# Is there a names() equivalent in Julia?

Tags: r, julia

I am transferring a script written in R to Julia, and one of the R functions is the names() function. Is there a synonymous function in Julia?

Comment: Just noting that both answers you have gotten are equally valid based on the level of detail in the question. R uses `names` for both the columns of a `DataFrame` as well as the fields of an object. Julia uses `names` for the columns of a `DataFrame` but `fieldnames` for the fields of an object.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### DataFrames

In Julia there is `names` function for a `DataFrame` which returns column names, e.g.:

```
julia> using DataFrames

julia> x = DataFrame(rand(3,4))
3×4 DataFrames.DataFrame
│ Row │ x1        │ x2       │ x3       │ x4       │
├─────┼───────────┼──────────┼──────────┼──────────┤
│ 1   │ 0.721198  │ 0.605882 │ 0.191941 │ 0.597295 │
│ 2   │ 0.0537836 │ 0.619698 │ 0.764937 │ 0.273197 │
│ 3   │ 0.679952  │ 0.899523 │ 0.206124 │ 0.928319 │

julia> names(x)
4-element Array{Symbol,1}:
 :x1
 :x2
 :x3
 :x4
```

Then in order to set column names of a `DataFrame` you can use `names!` function (example continued):

```
julia> names!(x, [:a,:b,:c,:d])
3×4 DataFrames.DataFrame
│ Row │ a         │ b        │ c        │ d        │
├─────┼───────────┼──────────┼──────────┼──────────┤
│ 1   │ 0.721198  │ 0.605882 │ 0.191941 │ 0.597295 │
│ 2   │ 0.0537836 │ 0.619698 │ 0.764937 │ 0.273197 │
│ 3   │ 0.679952  │ 0.899523 │ 0.206124 │ 0.928319 │
```

#### Arrays

Standard arrays do not support naming their dimensions. But you can use [NamedArrays.jl](https://github.com/davidavdav/NamedArrays.jl) package which adds this functionality. You can get and set names of dimensions as well as names of indices along each dimension. You can find the details here https://github.com/davidavdav/NamedArrays.jl#general-functions.

Comment: Thank you! I am new to Julia, and I am having trouble figuring out how to apply the package after downloading it from github. Can you offer any advice?

Comment: If you are new I recommend to use Julia 0.6.3. You can read how to do it here https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/manual/packages/#Adding-and-Removing-Packages-1. But the short instruction is the following. Write `Pkg.add("DataFrames")` (similar to `install.packages` in R) to install DataFrames.jl package. Then write `using DataFrames` to be able to start using it (similar to `library` in R).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an R expert but I think you want `fieldnames`

```
type Foo
    bar::Int
end
@show fieldnames(Foo)
baz = Foo(2)
@show fieldnames(baz)
```